# How can I get this kind of Color Picker View in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolorpickerviewcontroller

I would like to implement a `ColorPickerView Controller` in my app like this in the picture.
But I don't know what this circle element is called and may I make that object bigger?
[image]

I have encountered a ColorPickerViewController that is presented modally as a complete another scene but at this moment, I would like to implement a color picker as **a little window** without opening a new window.
Please, tell me how I can implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do that without opening it modally. That is the UIColorPickerViewController in UIKit, or ColorPicker in SwiftUI. It looks like this in iOS 14.
[image: iOS 14 ColorPicker]

and in iPadOS 14 it would look like this
[image: iPadOS 14 ColorPicker]

In SwiftUI it can be created like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var color = Color(.blue)

var body: some View {
        ColorPicker("Color", selection: $color)
            .padding(.horizontal, 150)
}
```

}

and in UIKit it is like this

```
// Initializing Color Picker
let picker = UIColorPickerViewController()

// Setting the Initial Color of the Picker

picker.selectedColor = self.view.backgroundColor!

// Setting Delegate
picker.delegate = self

// Presenting the Color Picker
self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For more information you can take a look at these websites:

- UIKit: https://www.swiftpal.io/articles/how-to-use-uicolorpickerviewcontroller-in-swift
- Swift UI: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-select-a-color-with-colorpicker

Now Additionally, if you really want it to be in a little window, you can use a PopOver and create your own color picker, it is a bit of work but shouldn't be too hard.

Here are some resources that might help you:

- SwiftUI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Wbyje-TMME
- UIKit: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-create-popover-menus-using-uipopoverpresentationcontroller
- More UIKit: http://www.thomashanning.com/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/

Comment: Thank you! Will read what you suggested. And I hope I may come back to you ;)

Comment: If I create this kind of `UIColorPickerViewController` in Xcode 12, it will work as expected only on devices which are updated to iOS 14, right? What happens if users didn't update their mobile OS? ...what are these all gonna look like?

Comment: Also, I haven't  updated my phone to iOS 14 and it has this UIColorPickerViewController. How is it done?

Comment: Hi,
The UIColorPickerViewController will only work on iOS 14.0 and up, so you can't use that if your deployment target in lower than iOS 14. This shouldn't be a big problem because most users would have updated to iOS 14, but if you wanted to support older iOS versions you can use a color picker created by someone else, here's one I found, it supports iOS 13 and up. https://github.com/maysamsh/SwiftColorPicker

Answer (score 0):

On button action, use the below code.

```swift
@IBAction func colorPickerTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

let colorPickerVC = UIColorPickerViewController()
colorPickerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
colorPickerVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
present(colorPickerVC, animated: true)

let popOverVC = colorPickerVC.popoverPresentationController
popOverVC?.sourceView = sender
colorPickerVC.delegate = self

}
```